# Null Reference Exception while uploading a file in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am developing CMS for a website using MVC 5 and Entity Framework. I have an edit form for editing the events added in the database table. I am uploading the image related to Event in a server folder and storing its URL in database.

Now I want to replace the

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image_Url, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

with a input with type `File`, so that anyone can change the image while editing the Event information. for this I have added following.

A `Picture` Class

```
public class Pictures
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

for File Uploading in `Edit Action Method` of controller

```
if (picture.File.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(picture.File.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/uploads/events/"), fileName);
    picture.File.SaveAs(path);
    filePath = "~/assets/uploads/events/" + fileName;
}
```

and finaly in `Edit` view

```
<input type="file" id="File" name="File" class="form-control" />
```

The above logic work perfectly fine when used in `Create` action method, but when I use the same in edit action method the `Null reference exception` occur. While debugging I found that the `picture.File` parameter is null at line `if (picture.File.ContentLength > 0)`.

This is working fine in `Create` but in `Edit` action method it returns `null`.

Any Help on this issue?

Comment: can you try using ``Request.Files`` in the action

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by using `Request.Files`. below is my code in controller Edit action method.

```
foreach(string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                fName = file.FileName;
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var orgDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/assets/uploads"));
                    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(orgDirectory.ToString(),"events");
                    var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
                    if(!isExists)
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                    }
                    var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName); //pathString + file.FileName;

                    file.SaveAs(path);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue could occur because of general security rules for the `<input type="file" />` as you can't set a value for it. So I think the only thing you can do is a create separate view for the re-creating the image for the profile, and each time user sends a picture to you treat is a new one.

Comment: Yes you are right. we can't set a value for '<input type="file">'. I have tried the @Ehsan Sajjad suggestion and it worked for me.